# how to add elements in a 2d array

Tags: java, eclipse

I just want to know how this program works, and why the answer is 14.
here is the code:

```
public class extra {
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[][] table = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    int sum = 0;
    for( int i = 2; i > 0; i-- ) 
              sum += table[i][3-i];
              System.out.println(sum);

}
```

}

I understand the way the matrix is set up

123

456

789

but what is i in this problem, because I thought it was the number of rows, but since it is in a for loop, does it mean that i is the number in the matrix? Also how do the [i][3-i] come in to affect? The answer is 14, and I just want to know how it is 14.

Answer (score 1):

It is only summing part of a diagonal, specifically `table[2][1]` which is 8, and `table[1][2]` which is 6.

The easiest way to see what is going on is to add an output statement in the loop:

```
for (int i = 2; i > 0; i--) {
  sum += table[i][3 - i];
  System.out.println(i + " " + (3 - i) + " " + table[i][3 - i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your program takes table[2][1] (value of 8) and table[1][2] (value of 6) elements, sums them and prints as output (value of 14)

regarding your question in a title your main method should be more like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] table = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    int sum = 0;

    System.out.println("Before\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {
            sum += table[i][j];
            System.out.printf("Sum after %d iteration: %d\n", i + j + 1, sum);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("\nIn total: " + sum);
}
```

i + j + 1 is a sum of current iteration which is sum of both axises, and since Java has 0-based indexed tables, it is increased by 1

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

`i`, in itself, does not correspond directly to anything in the matrix. It is just the name of the variable that the for loop changes each time it loops.

The `[i][3-i]` is how the `i` interacts with `table`. On the first round of the for loop, the `i` will be equal to 2. Thus, `sum` will be increased by `table[2][1]`, which is the 3rd row and the 2nd column of the matrix, which has a value of `8`.

On the second round of the for loop, the for loop, the `i` will be equal to 1. Thus, `sum` will be increased by `table[1][2]`, which is the 2nd row and the 3rd column of the matrix, which has a value of `6`.

Therefore, `sum` will be equal to 8+6=14.

Answer (score 0):

What the for loop does is as follows:

1. `i` = 2. Enter loop.
2. Add `table[2][3-2]` to sum. Sum is now 8, because `table[2][1]` = **8**.
3. Decrement `i` by 1.
4. `i` = 1. Enter loop.
5. Add `table[1][3-1]` to sum. Sum is now 14, because `table[1][2]` = **6**.
6. Decrement `i` by 1.
7. `i` = 0. 0 is not greater than 0, so we exit the loop. The sum became **14**.

---

Two-dimensional arrays like `int[][] table` have two indexes. One for the "outer" array (or rows), and one for the "inner" ones (columns).

Let's use `int[][] table = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};` from your code as an example:

`table[1][2]`: 1 means we should look in the array at index 1, which is `{4,5,6}`. 2 means we should look at `{4,5,6}`'s index 2, which is `6`. In other words `table[1][2] == 6`.

`table[2][0]`: 2 means we should look in the array at index 2, which is `{7,8,9}`. 0 means we should look at `{7,8,9}`'s index 0, which is `7`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 2; i > 0; i--)
```

so starting at 2 it checks if i is greater than zero
loops once then i-- subtracts 1
check again still greater than 0 
loops again then subtracts 1 again
checks if greater than 0 now 0 it is not greater than 0 so stops looping
//thus loops 2 times

```
//[0] = 1st [1] = 2nd [2] = third ...

//counting in code starts at zero not 1 so and array of 3 counts a the spaces 0,1,2

int sum = 0;//sum starts at zero

//using the value of i translates as such

sum += table[2][3-2];//[2][1]this is 3rd group 2nd part so sum += 8
//then
sum += table[1][3-1];//[1][2]this is 2nd group 3rd part so sum += 6
```

0 + 8 + 6 = 14

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to add elements in a 2D array in a easy way.
**First** when you initialize a 2D array think of the first brackets [ ] as a column and the second bracket [ ] as column rows. 
For example: `int[][] num = new int[10][5]` which means 10 columns and 5 rows.

If you want to fill all the elements in a 2D array you must use two ***for*** loops:

```
int[][] num = new int[10][5];

for (int i =0; i < num.length;i++ ) {
     for (int x=0; x < num[0].length;i++) { //we used num[0] because we need the length of the rows not the columns
           num[i][x] = //any value you want to assign
          }
 }
```